# Laptop is not turning on after suspending it

Tags: nvidia, suspend, intel-graphics, 22.10, integrated

I recently bought a new MSI GF63 Thin 11UC and installed Ubuntu 22.10 in it. Whenever I suspend my laptop it doesn't wake up anymore. I have to hard press the power button to shut it down and then turn the switch again. My specs, kernel and drivers:

i7-11th gen 11800H

NVIDIA RTX3050

Ubuntu 22.10

Linux 5.19.0-29-generic

Nvidia 525-proprietry-tested

#### EDIT 23 Jan 2023

I found out that things work perfect on xorg but not on wayland, however, the thing is the devices wakes up from suspend but the screen remains black when I'm using the integrated graphics, here tigerlake UHD graphics. Anyone knows any fix please help

Comment: That is a hardware issue (turning on from suspend is done by your hardware not through the OS). Try hibernate. Might be fixed with a BIOS update. If you have an ssd forget about suspend and turn the machine off when you need to travel. Speed up boot process by disabling not needed services (mine boots up in 8 seconds). No moving parts so no wear and tear if you do that.

Comment: Hey, I got a little more details about my problem, can you help me anyways now?